# is it possible to have other text blend effects in ffmpeg other than transparency? eg multiply or difference

Tags: ffmpeg

In ffmpeg it is straightforward using alpha to set a transparency when using drawtext,  but is it possible to have more complex effects?  eg if I want to blend text using difference or multiply?

I am guessing it is not possible with drawtext directly is it possible to simulate this using other features of ffmpeg?

The blend functionality is extremely powerful:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Blend

But I don't see how I can add text to a video with drawtext and use those blending options.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.

Answer (score 0):

add drawtext

```
ffmpeg -lavfi "
color=s=256x256,
geq=r='H-1-Y':g='H-1-Y':b='H-1-Y',
split[a][b];
[b]transpose,
drawtext=text='TEST'
:borderw=5
:bordercolor=orange
:fontsize=h/3
:fontcolor=green
:x=(w-tw)/2
:y=(h-th)/2[b];
[a][b]blend=all_mode=multiply,
pseudocolor=preset=turbo
" -frames:v 1 -y "out.png"
```

`color=...,geq=...` creates [gradient image](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/wiki/Blend/test.png), then split image to 2 streams: [a] and [b], etc -> [Filtering Introduction](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Filtering-Introduction)

Comment: if this works, it is amazing, I will test,  is it possible to add a few comments,  how is [a][b] working? also what is this doing : geq=r='H-1-Y':g='H-1-Y':b='H-1-Y',

Comment: What does 'H-1-Y' mean in `geq=r='H-1-Y':g='H-1-Y':b='H-1-Y'`?
I have seen it around quite a few times but no one cares to explain it ...
It looks like it sets R, G and B channels ...

Comment: @Apostolos , H is Height, Y is position, you can replace `H-1-Y` with `255-Y`

Comment: Thanks. So, you mean e.g. `r=255-Y` sets the red value?  But then what is the value of 'Y'???, Part of the mystery is gone, but it's still there! :)

Comment: I have sorted it all out now. One can simply use RGB colors. E.g. `geq=r='255':g='H-1-Y':b='H-1-Y'` will produce shades from red through pink to white, `geq=r='255':g='128':b='0'` will produce a solid orange, etc. 
Thanks for your help! 